# WP HTML minification class not working

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, minify

I found this script on http://www.intert3chmedia.net/2011/12/minify-html-javascript-css-without.html. It's supposed to minify (not compress as the class name suggests) HTML:

```
<?php
class WP_HTML_Compression
{
    // Settings
    protected $compress_css = true;
    protected $compress_js = true;
    protected $info_comment = true;
    protected $remove_comments = true;

    // Variables
    protected $html;
    public function __construct($html)
    {
        if (!empty($html))
        {
            $this->parseHTML($html);
        }
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->html;
    }
    protected function bottomComment($raw, $compressed)
    {
        $raw = strlen($raw);
        $compressed = strlen($compressed);

        $savings = ($raw-$compressed) / $raw * 100;

        $savings = round($savings, 2);

        return '<!--HTML compressed, size saved '.$savings.'%. From '.$raw.' bytes, now '.$compressed.' bytes-->';
    }
    protected function minifyHTML($html)
    {
        $pattern = '/<(?<script>script).*?<\/script\s*>|<(?<style>style).*?<\/style\s*>|<!(?<comment>--).*?-->|<(?<tag>[\/\w.:-]*)(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^\'">]+)*>|(?<text>((<[^!\/\w.:-])?[^<]*)+)|/si';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $overriding = false;
        $raw_tag = false;
        // Variable reused for output
        $html = '';
        foreach ($matches as $token)
        {
            $tag = (isset($token['tag'])) ? strtolower($token['tag']) : null;

            $content = $token[0];

            if (is_null($tag))
            {
                if ( !empty($token['script']) )
                {
                    $strip = $this->compress_js;
                }
                else if ( !empty($token['style']) )
                {
                    $strip = $this->compress_css;
                }
                else if ($content == '<!--wp-html-compression no compression-->')
                {
                    $overriding = !$overriding;

                    // Don't print the comment
                    continue;
                }
                else if ($this->remove_comments)
                {
                    if (!$overriding && $raw_tag != 'textarea')
                    {
                        // Remove any HTML comments, except MSIE conditional comments
                        $content = preg_replace('/<!--(?!\s*(?:\[if [^\]]+]|<!|>))(?:(?!-->).)*-->/s', '', $content);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ($tag == 'pre' || $tag == 'textarea')
                {
                    $raw_tag = $tag;
                }
                else if ($tag == '/pre' || $tag == '/textarea')
                {
                    $raw_tag = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($raw_tag || $overriding)
                    {
                        $strip = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $strip = true;

                        // Remove any empty attributes, except:
                        // action, alt, content, src
                        $content = preg_replace('/(\s+)(\w++(?<!\baction|\balt|\bcontent|\bsrc)="")/', '$1', $content);

                        // Remove any space before the end of self-closing XHTML tags
                        // JavaScript excluded
                        $content = str_replace(' />', '/>', $content);
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($strip)
            {
                $content = $this->removeWhiteSpace($content);
            }

            $html .= $content;
        }

        return $html;
    }

    public function parseHTML($html)
    {
        $this->html = $this->minifyHTML($html);

        if ($this->info_comment)
        {
            $this->html .= "\n" . $this->bottomComment($html, $this->html);
        }
    }

    protected function removeWhiteSpace($str)
    {
        $str = str_replace("\t", ' ', $str);
        $str = str_replace("\n",  '', $str);
        $str = str_replace("\r",  '', $str);

        while (stristr($str, '  '))
        {
            $str = str_replace('  ', ' ', $str);
        }

        return $str;
    }
}

function wp_html_compression_finish($html)
{
    return new WP_HTML_Compression($html);
}

function wp_html_compression_start()
{
    ob_start('wp_html_compression_finish');
}
add_action('get_header', 'wp_html_compression_start');
?>
```

My HTML has IE conditionals at the top, something like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Everything below the IE conditionals is minified correctly. The result is one long line of HTML. The problem is that everything above the IE conditionals does not seem to be minified. The carriage returns are still preserved. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: How do you actually use the minification functions/methods?

Comment: Yes. The IE conditionals do not get minified.

Comment: You misunderstand me.  Where do you call the functions, and what is your html?

Comment: The WP hooks handle the calls. In any case, you don't need to rely on the hooks. Just instantiate the class and pass it unminified HTML.

Comment: Uh huh .. and what is your unminified HTML?

Comment: Any HTML with IE conditionals should show this problem.

Comment: I've used this class with my WP template but it seems to work pretty fine ! can you please put the part which is not minified that we can have a look at it ?

Comment: Also, please pay attention, when I used this class, some of my jquery scripts didn't work any more !!! you have to consider that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site just took the code and renamed it. Somehow using "their" code is better than using the actual plugin? Oh well.

There's a newer version available for both WordPress and standard PHP:
http://www.svachon.com/blog/html-minify/

Comment: Hi Steven, were you the original author of the script?

Comment: Yes, and am still maintaining it as well.

Answer (score 4):

how about a custom method?

```
public static function html_compress($buffer)
{
    $chunks = preg_split( '/(<pre.*?\/pre>)/ms', $buffer, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
    $buffer = '';
    $replace = array(
        '#[\n\r\t\s]+#'           => ' ',  // remove new lines & tabs
        '#>\s{2,}<#'              => '><', // remove inter-tag whitespace
        '#\/\*.*?\*\/#i'          => '',   // remove CSS & JS comments
        '#<!--(?![\[>]).*?-->#si' => '',   // strip comments, but leave IF IE (<!--[...]) and "<!-->""
        '#\s+<(html|head|meta|style|/style|title|script|/script|/body|/html|/ul|/ol|li)#' => '<$1', // before those elements, whitespace is dumb, so kick it out!!
        '#\s+(/?)>#' => '$1>', // just before the closing of " >"|" />"
        '#class="\s+#'=> 'class="', // at times, there is whitespace before class=" className"
        '#(script|style)>\s+#' => '$1>', // <script> var after_tag_has_whitespace = 'nonsens';
    );
    $search = array_keys($replace);
    foreach ( $chunks as $c )
    {
        if ( strpos( $c, '<pre' ) !== 0 )
        {
            $c = preg_replace($search, $replace, $c);
        }
        $buffer .= $c;
    }
    return $buffer;
}
```

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/unamatasanatarai/HTMLCompress)

Comment: This is very similar to what the class is doing. What is the source of this script? Are there unit tests for it?

Comment: I've been using this for the past two years. No unit tests yet. Source is internet and my own regex proficiency. I created a https://github.com/unamatasanatarai/HTMLCompress which you may fork

Comment: Why do you replace `#[\n\r\t\s]+#` with a single space? Why `#>\s{2,}<#` is this "2 or more" instead of "1 or more"?

Comment: sometimes you have something like `<span>hello</span> world` so when you remove the space, you will get `helloworld`. Thus leaving one space after the closing `>`. Replacing enters, tabs and whitespaces with one space ensures that if you format your code with enters and tabs (which do result in displaying spaces) you do not find the above example. Hope this clarifies a bit. You are welcome to make it better! :)

Comment: Your example `<span>hello</span> world` doesn't apply to any of the regex I asked about. Your explanation about "enters, tabs and whitespaces with one space" does not make sense to me; why not replace with empty string again?

Answer (score 1):

Something else is amiss here.

I reduced this 'class' to a single page PHP script (replacing any $this-> calls with either true (in the case of the ivars) or a static function call.

Then I ran a variety of tests with long HTML input, and tried messing around with conditional comments, including copy-pasting in your conditional <html> tags that you had earlier.  Each time the results were a single line of output.

In conclusion, there are some possibilities:

1. There is something else in your HTML throwing it off (link to actual page?)
2. The minifying is occurring BEFORE the extra HTML is added (very possible)
3. One of the ivars is not true (unlikely)
4. Something is inserting `<!--wp-html-compression no compression-->` into that part of your document

Why not insert `error_log($html);` (or similar) at the beginning of the minifyHTML($html) method to see what the original HTML looked like.  My guess is that the results of that will tell you why it isn't working.  (you could just `return $html;` too I would guess.)

EDIT---
Here is my 'script', note that Conditional comments are left, and non-conditional HTML comments are stripped.  And I didn't bother with line formatting at all as it was just a hack job from the original class you provided.

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="desc" />
<meta name="keywords" content="c" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = '';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
    .single-call-to-action .action-text {
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66000000, endColorstr=#66000000);
    }
    #PaypalSideBar a img {
        left: 0 !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        width: 182px !important;
        height: 96px !important;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
    .single-call-to-action .action-text {
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66000000, endColorstr=#66000000)";
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>

<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/test.css" media="all" />

<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/test.css" media="all" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/test.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/test.js"></script><![endif]-->


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Mage.Cookies.path     = '/';
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
optionalZipCountries = ["US"];
//]]>
</script>
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODEs -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-x']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    window.HDUSeed = 'x';
    window.HDUSeedIntId = setInterval(function() {
        if (document.observe) {
            document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
                    if (document.forms[i].getAttribute('action') && document.forms[i].getAttribute('action').match('contacts/index/post')) {
                        var el = document.createElement('input');
                        el.type = ('hidden');
                        el.name = 'hdu_seed';
                        el.value = window.HDUSeed;
                        document.forms[i].appendChild(el);

                    }
                }
            });
            clearInterval(window.HDUSeedIntId)
        }
    }, 100)
    //]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate([]);
        //]]></script><meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>

   <style type="text/css">
   /*default iteaser*/
   #TT2ILTbox {
     background-color: #f3f3f3;
     border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 280px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-top: 10px;
   }

   #TT2ILTbox h2 {
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
   }

   #TT2ILTcount-line * {
     font-size: 11px;
   }

   #TT2ILTcount-line strong {
     font: bold 11px Arial;
   }

   #TT2ILTcount-line p {
     margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
   }

   #TT2ILTbutton-holder {
     display: -moz-box !important;
     display: block;
     height: 31px;
     text-align: center;
   }

   a.TT2ILTbutton, a.TT2ILTbutton span {
     background-color: #fa002f;
   }

   .TT2ILTbutton * {
     font: bold 12px Arial;

   }

   a.TT2ILTbutton {
     background-image: url('http://static.www.turnto.com/tra2/images/iteaser/1/button-right.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: top right;
     display: block;
     height: 31px;
     margin-right: 6px;
     padding-right: 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
   }

   a.TT2ILTbutton span {
     background-image: url('http://static.www.turnto.com/tra2/images/iteaser/1/button-left.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     display: block;
     line-height: 22px;
     padding: 2px 0 7px 18px;
   }

   a.TurnToIteaSee {
     font-size: 11px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #000;
     cursor: pointer;
   }
   </style>


</head>
<body class=" cms-index-index cms-home">
<div class="wrapper">
        <noscript>
        <div class="global-site-notice noscript">
            <div class="notice-inner">
                <p>
                    <strong>JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser.</strong><br />
                    You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to utilize the functionality of this website.                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </noscript>
    <div class="page">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


EOF;

function removeWhiteSpace($str)
    {
        $str = str_replace("\t", ' ', $str);
        $str = str_replace("\n",  '', $str);
        $str = str_replace("\r",  '', $str);

        while (stristr($str, '  '))
        {
            $str = str_replace('  ', ' ', $str);
        }

        return $str;
    }


$pattern = '/<(?<script>script).*?<\/script\s*>|<(?<style>style).*?<\/style\s*>|<!(?<comment>--).*?-->|<(?<tag>[\/\w.:-]*)(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^\'">]+)*>|(?<text>((<[^!\/\w.:-])?[^<]*)+)|/si';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $overriding = false;
        $raw_tag = false;
        // Variable reused for output
        $html = '';
        foreach ($matches as $token)
        {
            $tag = (isset($token['tag'])) ? strtolower($token['tag']) : null;

            $content = $token[0];

            if (is_null($tag))
            {
                if ( !empty($token['script']) )
                {
                    $strip = true;
                }
                else if ( !empty($token['style']) )
                {
                    $strip = true;
                }
                else if ($content == '<!--wp-html-compression no compression-->')
                {
                    $overriding = !$overriding;

                    // Don't print the comment
                    continue;
                }
                else if (true)
                {
                    if (!$overriding && $raw_tag != 'textarea')
                    {
                        // Remove any HTML comments, except MSIE conditional comments
                        $content = preg_replace('/<!--(?!\s*(?:\[if [^\]]+]|<!|>))(?:(?!-->).)*-->/s', '', $content);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ($tag == 'pre' || $tag == 'textarea')
                {
                    $raw_tag = $tag;
                }
                else if ($tag == '/pre' || $tag == '/textarea')
                {
                    $raw_tag = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($raw_tag || $overriding)
                    {
                        $strip = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $strip = true;

                        // Remove any empty attributes, except:
                        // action, alt, content, src
                        $content = preg_replace('/(\s+)(\w++(?<!\baction|\balt|\bcontent|\bsrc)="")/', '$1', $content);

                        // Remove any space before the end of self-closing XHTML tags
                        // JavaScript excluded
                        $content = str_replace(' />', '/>', $content);
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($strip)
            {
                $content = removeWhiteSpace($content);
            }

            $html .= $content;
        }

        echo $html;
```

Comment: Sure, but its going to be a lot as I was pretty through at testing.